# List not displaying after adding elements to array

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster, angular8

I have a list of elements recovered from a URL like this.

```
 queryByDepartamentoEstado(departamento: number, estatus: EstatusRequisicion, req?: any): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);

    return this.http.get<IRequisicion[]>(`${this.resourceUrl}/departamento/${departamento}/estatus/${estatus}`, {
     params: options,
     observe: 'response'
    })
    .pipe(map((res: EntityArrayResponseType) => this.mapeaInfoDeptos(res)));
```

then the result is sent to this method, which is empty (for now)

```
  protected mapeaInfoDeptos( res: EntityArrayResponseType ): EntityArrayResponseType{


    return res;
  }
```

an this is the result.

[image: List displayed]

now if I add this into the method **mapeaInfoDeptos**

```
  protected mapeaInfoDeptos( res: EntityArrayResponseType ): EntityArrayResponseType{

    let idsDepartamentos: number[];


    if (res.body) {
      res.body.forEach((requisicion: IRequisicion) => {
        idsDepartamentos.push( requisicion.requeridoPorId ? 0 : 1);//With this the code does not run
         requisicion.sedeId ;
      });
    }

    return res;
  }
```

as you can see I'm trying to add an element from the entity **IRequisicion** to the array **idsDepartamentos**, after adding this piece of code the list it is not displayed, I checked in the developer tools (chrome ) and in the console from where the app is launched but no error is displayed.

Thank you for any advice or help you can provide.

Comment: Didn't you forget to `subscribe()` ?

Comment: Try reproducing it on stackblitz